# How to make sure the width of the table columns are the same?

Tags: html

I am a newbie to HTML5. Now I started to build a table for multiplication. It seems alright but when adding two digits numbers on the table, the width of the columns are not the same. How to make the columns have the same width?[The table I built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K2k1.png)[The desired table I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnQzU.png)

Here are the code I wrote. Even I enter the width of the table is 1200px, it cannot give the output that I want. How to solve the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th{
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
td{
    text-align:center;
}
#d1{
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
</style>
<table width="1200">
<tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>9</th>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="d1">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="d1">2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just fix the width add this to your css under td

```
width: 50px;
```

result :

```
td{
    text-align:center;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/nqgktmtm/)

```
td{
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
}
```